# want to access strings in a fragment from xml

Tags: android

I want to access string name from xml into this string array but it gives me null object error , what should I do ? how can I access this string ? I have used context but it isn't working ,can someone tell me how can I do it ?

```
public class ViewProfileAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
    Context context;
    String a=context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_kundli);
    String b=context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_remedies);
    String c=context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_predictions);
    String d=context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_panchang);

    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] {a,b,c,d };

    public ViewProfileAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return ViewKundli_1.newInstance(position);

            case 1:
                return ViewKundli_2.newInstance(position);

            case 2:
                return ViewKundli_3.newInstance(position);

            case 3:
                return ViewKundli_4.newInstance(position);

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];

    }

}
```

Comment: You are not initializing your context variable. Just use getApplicationContext().getResources()....

Comment: @bipin you can Accept the helped answer bellow any one that other people get help from your contribution :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `getActivity()` instead of `context.getApplicationContext().` for fragment.
And for your adaptor, You should use a constructor to initialize the context variable and then alone `context` will work

Comment: it's a fragment not activity so how can i use getActivity() ? it gives me error

Answer (score 2):

Create constructor in `ViewProfileAdapter` class and pass context in constructor now use `StringArray` instead `string`

In **ViewProfileAdapter.java**

```
private Context context;
private String[] tabTitleArray = null;

public ViewProfileAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
        Context context) {
    super(fm);
    tabTitleArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.tab_title);
    this.context= context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabTitleArray.length();
}
```

In your `Fragment` or `Activity`

```
ViewProfileAdapter pageAdapter 
                           = new ViewProfileAdapter(getFragmentManager(), this);
 //this- Activity and getActivty() for Fragment
```

In **string.xml**

```
<string-array name="tab_titles">
   <item>tab1</item>
   <item>tab2</item>
   <item>tab3</item>
    <item>tab4</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: its working now thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

`getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_kundli)` directly works in case of fragments

Comment: String a=getString(R.string.view_kundli_menu);      not working

Comment: are you getting some error.. can you share your error logs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor to your class :

```
public ViewProfileAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

And in your activity :

```
ViewProfileAdapter adapter = new ViewProfileAdapter(this);
//etc...
```

Then you are good to go to use :

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_kundli);
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Context member was not initialized.
You need to pass Context to Adapter and then use it as a reference.
You can not, in this case, initialize Strings within field declaration.

```
Context context;
String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;

private String[] tabTitles;

public ViewProfileAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    a=context.getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_kundli);
    b=context.getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_remedies);
    c=context.getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_predictions);
    d=context.getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_panchang);
    tabTitles = new String[] {a,b,c,d };
}

// If you need String elsewhere

void method() {
    String s = context.getString(R.string.s);
}
```

Or even better

```
private final String[] tabTitles;

public ViewProfileAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    tabTitles = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_titles);
}
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="tab_titles">
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
    <item>c</item>
    <item>d</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my answer to suite your requirement.

```
public class ViewProfileAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
    Context context; 
    String a; 
    String b;  
    String c;
    String d;

    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] {a,b,c,d };

    public ViewProfileAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
    this.context = context;//this assignment is for future use of context object
    a=context.getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_kundli);
        b=context.getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_remedies);
        c=context.getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_predictions);
        d=context.getResources().getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_panchang);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return ViewKundli_1.newInstance(position);

            case 1:
                return ViewKundli_2.newInstance(position);

            case 2:
                return ViewKundli_3.newInstance(position);

            case 3:
                return ViewKundli_4.newInstance(position);

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];

    }

}
```

call the above constructer as below from your Activity

```
new ViewProfileAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity());//Support lib
new ViewProfileAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity());//without support lib and Android API greater than 3.0
```

call the above constructer as below from your Fragment

```
new ViewProfileAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity());
```

Comment: I'm not sure `ViewProfileAdapter` is actually an inner class of a Fragment. Anyway, this is still not the best approach. It is better to pass Context in a constructor, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: whether you pass  Context or not it is still part of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize context in your Application class something like this,

public class Application extends Application {

```
private static Context context;

public static synchronized Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;

    );
}
```

}

and then in your Adapter you can use this context as

Resources resources = Application.getContext().getResources();

a = resources.getString(R.string.viewkundli_tab_kundli);